# Sentiment analysis, are my samples significantly different?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, chi-squared-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, sentiment-analysis

I have extracted data from a reviews website. I have created a dictionary with all words that appear in the reviews and corresponding number of counts.

I have then spit the reviews into two samples: reviews_plus (reviews with 7 stars or more) and reviews_minus (7 or less).

I have finally populated the two samples with the number of times a given word appears in a given sentiment-review, such as:

reviews_plus = {"the" : 1238, "ruin": 18, "hot": 291, etc...}

reviews_minus = {"the" : 1134, "ruin" : 87, "hot": 341, etc...}

Now I would like to test if the two samples are consistently different or not, a.k.a. if people giving bad and good reviews use different vocabularies.

I have read around the topic for two days but I am really stuck. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two types of reviews (but many words), the easiest thing to do would be to run exact Fisher's test. You can do it in R using the function [fisher.test](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/fisher.test.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Fisher's test didn't pop up in my mind, it looks like the right choice. I was also thinking about Wilcoxon signed rank test. Would it be OK as well?